# ExecuteCommand on Entity

Tags: mysql, linq, entity, execute

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write(Execute("SELECT NOW()"));
}

public string Execute(string storedProcedureName)
{
    using (EntityConnection connection = (EntityConnection)new EGModel.EGEntity().Connection)
    {
        using (EntityCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            command.CommandText = storedProcedureName;
            connection.Open();
            return command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting error "The query syntax is not valid. Near line 1, column 13."; I am very curious, why this error?
(Mysql Entity Connection)

Comment: SQL Server? Try SELECT GETDATE() AS CurrentDateTime;

Comment: I am using MySQL Server, But SELECT NOW() is runing on QueryBrowser, no error.

Comment: To rule out the `NOW()` function, try `SELECT 'test'` and see if that returns properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var A = new EGModel.EGEntity().Connection;

    var command = ((EntityConnection)(A)).StoreConnection.CreateCommand();
    command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
    command.CommandText = "SELECT NOW()";
    ((EntityConnection)(A)).StoreConnection.Open();
    string id = (string)command.ExecuteScalar();
```

@GTSouza Thank you for your comments,